# Deserialize HttpContext context response in asp.net core middleware

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to Deserialize HttpContext context response in my exception middleware 
like

```
context.Response.Deserialize<myclasss>();
```

if it deserilizes successfully according to **myclass** i want to send a specific respponse object back like

```
 StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
 Message = "something went wrong"
```

Comment: I am receiving response in HttpContext context,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way of resolving the same. Define a model for your error messages. Let that be `ApiError`

```
public class ErrorDetailsVM
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can create your own Middleware that will always send back the ErrorDetailsVM object after serializing it. Following is an example of the middleware.

```
public class DeveloperExceptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DeveloperExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext) //If you have additional dependencies, you can inject them here. 
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log your errors here. Then send back the client a response.
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetailsVM()
        {
            Message = exception.Message,
            Exception=exception.ToString(),
            StackTrace=exception.StackTrace,
            Source = exception.Source
        }.ToString());
    }
}
```

And finally, inside your `Startup.cs` you can add the following lines to the `Configure` method.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseCustomDeveloperException();
```

Similarly, you can have a separate `UseCustomProductionException` middleware for production that sends out less internal information. Let me know if this solves your issue.

> Happy Coding <3

Comment: heey that looks great thankyou so much for the effort i am going through it :)

Comment: Hey @Aamir, if this solves your problem, please mark this as an answer and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

in this case i use

```
context.Response.ReadAsString().Deserilize<MyClass>()
```

using NewtonSoft.Josn library to deserilize

Comment: actudally iam working in asp.net core so can you seuggest a solution according to it